# Wordpress custom meta field for custom post not storing data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I have created custom post type named as freebie in that i have created a custom meta section in that added a input field. Which is not storing the data which entered in that field also not displaying the values entered in that field. I have attached the coding.

```
function adding_freebie_metabox($post) {

    add_meta_box(
          'my-meta-box'
        , __('Freebie extra deatails', 'lwprjs')
        , 'render_my_freebie_metabox'
        , 'freebie'
        , 'normal'
        , 'default'
    );

}

add_action('add_meta_boxes_freebie', 'adding_freebie_metabox');

// Add field
function render_my_freebie_metabox($meta_id) {

    // make sure the form request comes from WordPress
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'freebie_meta_box_nonce');

    ?>

        Enter freebie details such as URL of download and also demo URL
        <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="freebie-demo">Demo URL</label></th>
                    <td><input style="width: 100%" id="freebie-demo" name="freebie-demo"
                        type="text"
                        value="<?php get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_field['freebie-demo'], true ); ?>"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <?php
}

function food_save_meta_box_data($post_id) {

    // verify meta box nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['freebie_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['freebie_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return;
    }

    // return if autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return;
    }

    // store custom fields values
    // cholesterol string
    if (isset($_REQUEST['freebie-demo'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_freebie_demo', sanitize_text_field($_POST['freebie-demo']));
    }
}

add_action('save_post_freebie', 'food_save_meta_box_data');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, hope you have already register your CPT(custom post type) providing valid label & arguments with function:

```
register_post_type( 'freebie', $args );
```

Here is the complete code that, your custom meta box will be only visible to our "freebie" CPT with a input field  to save demo url for this CPT posts. Add the below lines of code your functions.php

```
// Adding meta box for freebie custom post type
function demo_url_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        'demo_url_meta_box',
        __( 'Demo URL', '' ),
        'demo_url_meta_box_callback',
        'freebie',
        'side',
        'low'

    );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_freebie', 'demo_url_meta_box' );
// Callback function of metabox
function demo_url_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'demo_url_nonce', 'demo_url_nonce' );

    // postmeta key: _demo_url
    $demo_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_demo_url', true );


    echo '<textarea style="width:100%" id="freebie-demo" name="freebie-demo">' . esc_attr( $demo_url ) . '</textarea>';
}
/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 */
function save_demo_url_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['demo_url_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['demo_url_nonce'], 'demo_url_nonce' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    }
    else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['freebie-demo'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $de_url = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['freebie-demo'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_demo_url', $de_url );
}
// add meta box data when save_post is hooked
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_demo_url_meta_box_data' );
```

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: If multiple fields need to be inserted what needs to be done ?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303187/problem-with-adding-exta-field-in-metabox-in-custom-post-type

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to add a different template for showing that.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );
```

On top of  the php

```
function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'freebies-info' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'freebies-info.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/freebies_info.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
```

This part `if ( get_post_type() == 'freebies-info' ) {` should be your `register_post_type` instead of `freebies-info`
This code for adding the php file, i used for example `freebies-info.php`.
Then create a php file called that, in the same folder.
This might look like this:

```
<?php
 /*Template Name: New Template
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'freebies-info', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
                <strong>Title: </strong><?php the_title(); ?><br />
            </header>
                <div class="">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Remember that i made this freebies-info for yo.

```
$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'freebies-info', );
```

Here you should put whatever you have called your `register_post_type` that you can find where you created your costum post type.

Hope this helps you or that you get some more ideas how to fix it, Goodluck!