# Problem with adding exta field in metabox in custom post type

Tags: custom-field, metabox, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add a new field in the metabox there is demo url field which is working fine i have created new field that is not storing or saving any datas which inserted into the field.

Here is my coading.

```
// Adding meta box for freebie custom post type
function demo_url_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        'demo_url_meta_box',
        __( 'Freebie Details', '' ),
        'demo_url_meta_box_callback',
        'freebie',
        'normal',
        'low'

    );
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_freebie', 'demo_url_meta_box' );
// Callback function of metabox
function demo_url_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'demo_url_nonce', 'demo_url_nonce' );

    // postmeta key: _demo_url
    $demo_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_demo_url', true );
    ?>
Enter freebie details such as URL of download and also demo URL
<table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th><label for="freebie-demo">Enter demo URL</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" id="freebie-demo" name="freebie-demo" value="<?php echo $demo_url; ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th><label for="freebie-downurl">Enter Download URL</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" id="freebie-downurl" name="freebie-downurl" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>    

<?php
}
/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 */
function save_demo_url_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['demo_url_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['demo_url_nonce'], 'demo_url_nonce' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    }
    else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['freebie-demo'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $de_url = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['freebie-demo'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_demo_url', $de_url );


}
// add meta box data when save_post is hooked
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_demo_url_meta_box_data' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't retrieve your 2 values in the save_post action.

You need to get $_POST[’freebie-demo’] (it's ok for it) and $_POST['freebie-downurl']

If you want an array post meta value based, you can do something like that :

```
// Sanitize user input.
$de_url['name'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['freebie-demo'] );
$de_url['url'] = esc_url($_POST['freebie-downurl']);

// Update the meta field in the database.
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_demo_url', $de_url );
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: It was not working .